# AWS Amplify Push Notifications support for non-ejected CRNA apps

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

The AWS-Amplify documentation [here](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/push_notifications_setup.html), describes in detail, how to setup notifications in a react native app.
But, from the looks of it, this will not work for non-ejected CRNA apps. Is there any way to configure push notifications using Amplify for non-ejected CRNA appsCRNA apps?